# Complex Yii SQL statement

Tags: sql, activerecord, yii

I'm new to Yii and I have difficulties to translate an SQL query to Yii Active Record language or with the query builder.

I have 3 tables :
- Post : id, text
- Tag : id, name
- Post_Tag : id_post, id_tag

What i want to do is to be able to select the posts that have all tags selected by the user :
Here is the SQL statement that works and that i want to translate to Yii language :

```
SELECT * FROM Post p INNER JOIN tags pt ON p.id=pt.post_id WHERE pt.tag_id in(10, 13) group by pt.post_id having count(distinct pt.tag_id) > 1;
```

Is someone got something to help me ? thanks in advance !

Comment: Start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015311/yii-cdbcriteria-complex-joins?rq=1 and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your query, you should be able to do something like this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(); 
$criteria->join = "INNER JOIN tags pt ON t.id=pt.post_id"; 
$criteria->addInCondition("pt.tag_id", array(10,13));
$criteria->group = "t.id";
$criteria->having = "COUNT(DISTINCT pt.tag_id) > 1";

$posts = Posts::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

If you want all posts with a certain tag, you could use the Tags model with some relations.

In your Tag model file:

```
public function relations()
{   
    return array(
        'postTags' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'PostsTags', 'tag_id'),
        'posts' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Posts', array('post_id'=>'id'), 'through'=>'postTags'),
        //Other relations here
    );
}
```

Then you can get the posts for a tag like this:

```
$tag = Tags::model()->findByPk(10);
$posts = $tag->posts;
```

You can add conditions to the relations if you want to filter

Comment: thank you very much, i finally did it thanks to your explanations !