# How to join 3 tables in CDbCriteria and access those values from CGridView

Tags: yii, cgridview

I'm newbie to yii and I want to know:

How to **JOIN** 3 tables in  **CDbCriteria** and access those values from **CGridView**

My table:

```
invoice     (IID,date,cusID)  PK = IID
invoiceItem (invIID, IID, itemID, date, cusID)  PK= invIID   FK = IID
item        (itemID, name, price, cat)  PK = itemID
```

I just need to **JOIN** these three tables and show on **CGridView**. 
If you have any tutorials,notes regarding this please provide.

Please help. 
Thanks.

Comment: You need to define relations within models and use `with` field of CDbCriteria.

Comment: See [following link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14774541/1746258) and here is [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-options) here you can read how to convert `sql query` to `yii` code

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this creating relations
In **item** model

```
'invoices' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'invoiceItem', 'itemID'),
```

In **invoiceItem** model

```
'invoice' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'invoice', 'IID'),
```

Then any where in your view you could user it as follows

```
$item->invoices;  //returns array of invoiceItems objects

$item->invoices['index']->invoice; //return invoice object for that item.
```

This will generate the data for **item** model, to use for **invoice** , reverse relations.

Answer (score 1):

CDbCriteria has `join` property, where you can use SQL code for JOINs.

Answer (score 1):

using relations and for accessing to column use like this in cgridview params

```
'columns' => array(
    array('name' => 'columnname',
          'value' => 'isset($data->relationname) ? $data->relationname->name : ""' )
)
```

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code with criteria

```
$criteria->select = 't.*'; //specify list of columns you need
$criteria->join = 'INNER JOIN invoiceItem on t.invIID=invoiceItem.invIID INNER JOIN item on invoiceItem.itemID = item.itemID
```